# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, initializer-list

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct TDate
{
    int day, month, year;
    void Readfromkb()
    {
        cout << "\n ENTER DAY MONTH YEAR\n";
        cin >> day >> month >> year;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << day << month << year;
    }
    private:
        int ID;
        bool valid;

};
int main()
{
    TDate t1, t2,t3={ 1, 2, 3 };
    t1.Readfromkb();
    t1.print();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

why i'm getting Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'TDate' and     2   IntelliSense: too many initializer values. When I remove bool valid and int ID the programs works.Why is it so?

Comment: I do like this modern C++ way of initializing but found that in MSVS 2015 it won't work if you have struct fields initializers like `struct TDate { int day = 0; };` while this one works `struct TDate { int day; };`

Answer (score 8):

You are getting the error because you are trying to initialize a `TDate` from an aggregate initialization list. This cannot be done when the type has private members (such as, in your case, `ID` and `valid`).

You can work around this by providing a constructor for your struct from three `int`s and using `TDate t1, t2, t3(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

To do  `t3={ 1, 2, 3 };` you have to make constructor of TDate with takes three arguments, like this:

```
TDate(int i, int i1, int i2);
```

and implement it using:

```
TDate::TDate(int i, int i1, int i2) {

}
```

if you dont want to create constructor, then create object like this:

```
TDate t1 = TDate();
```

Comment: This article says otherwise: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt179298.aspx  (usually I'd never cite microsoft, but the question is tagged visual-studio).  You ought to be able to use an initializer list to initialize struct members in order of declaration.  I can't get it to work either though.